# jquery load callback to parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, coldfusion, nested

I have a form that submits to an iframe. The iframe process a coldfusion page which has this code:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.attachments', window.parent.document).load('itemAttachments.cfm?ID=' + <cfoutput>#ID#</cfoutput>, function(){
            styleForm();
            window.parent.document.alert();
        });
    });
</SCRIPT>
```

The styleForm() is in the parent document's javascript (the one that holds the initial form that was submitted). The load works fine, and the iframe properly updates the attachments div. But my callback function fails. I wonder if it has something to do with scope. You can see I tried to alter the scope on the alert I put in my callback. No alert is shown. Does anyone know where my problem is? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the function calls in itemAttachments.cfm and used a setTimeout so it would load after afterthing else was loaded.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT">
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.parent.styleForm();
        window.parent.deleteFileHandler();
    },250);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `parent.` to get to the parent window, like so:

```
parent.$('.attachments').load(...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Dan. I already got it working though. FWIF the load nor the scope of the selector were the problem. Those worked fine. The issue was with calling the functions in the callback. I had tried parent.functionCall() but that did not work :/